# VA-API Hardware decode does not work

Tags: drivers, graphics, video

I’m running a Chromebox which runs Ubuntu 20.04 (Celeron 3205U, Intel Broadwell-U Graphics, 4GB RAM, with the `intel-media-driver` driver installed. I’ve been trying to get hardware decode working, but Firefox and Chromium refuse to use it, even after changing the parameters in their configurations, and I’ve tried checking with `mpv` and `vlc` if VA-API Hardware decode works, but both of them seem to segfault when I open a normal MP4 video and specify using VA-API to decode. I notice in http that the memory usage spikes and that in `dmesg` there is an OOM event, however, I cannot find the root of the issue. I have also tried the i965 driver, the intel-media-driver-non-free, and others, but cannot solve the problem.

vainfo shows that VAAPI is enabled, but `intel_gpu_top` shows 0% usage of the Video unit. The hardware decode seems to work on the Chrome OS side of things, so I know it is not a hardware issue.

Comment: Please install vainfo by `sudo apt-get install vainfo` and then add `vainfo` output to the question by editing it.